# What is the maximum size limit on payload in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb, cloudhub

I am trying to send a 2 GB file using binary option in postman to Mule application.
Getting 413 Request entity too large error. There are no logs present in the Mule application so it seems its failing on APIKit router itself.

Is there any limit on the payload which can be sent to Mule application?
If yes, can it be increased?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to

> run->
>   run configuration->
>   arguments,
>   -M-XX:-UseBiasedLocking
>   -Xmx2048M